# Use a separate file for "scripts"

Tags: javascript, npm, package.json

In my package.json file, I have so many commands in "scripts" like the code below.

```
"scripts" {
  "script1": "command example",
  "script2": "command example",
  "script3": "command example",
  "script4": "command example",
  "script5": "command example",
  "script6": "command example",
  "script7": "command example",
  ...
}
```

Is there any way to move those commands to another file?

For instance, I'm thinking about moving them to a file like `bin/commands.js`.

Comment: What do you mean by _"too many"_? Is there an error being thrown or something?

Comment: @Phil I should have just said, "there are so many commands".
There isn't any error caused by this. I just want to separate all the commands for better readability.

Comment: You could use a Makefile as an alternative to package.json scripts

Comment: you can create a script which accepts a param depending on that run different scripts.

Comment: For the life of me, IDK why they ever choose to make it "ONLY" available in the package.json file. They made `.npmrc` a properties file, so JSON cant be used in that file. I'm writing this in 2022, and still, I don't see any good solutions for this. I am thinking about trying to engineer a new solution, but I am guessing if there was one it would have been implemented in a NPM module already...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a common problem, having your package.json get bloated from too many scripts. There is a pretty good solution built by Kent Dodds, called [NPS](https://github.com/kentcdodds/nps) (npm-package-scripts). Unfortunately there are not many solutions for this problem.

PRO: you define the script in a js file so you have more flexibility, reduces clutter in your package.json, good community support.

CON: Not many just a different command (nps vs npm)

Answer (score 3):

You can create a separate script as following

shell script

```
if [ $1 == "1" ]; then
        sh <path to script1>
elif [ $1 == "2"]; then
        sh <path to script2>
else
        echo "script does not exist"
fi
```

Node Script

```
{
    var exec = require('child-process-promise').exec;
    let args = process.argv[2];
    let obj = {
        "script1": "command example",
        "script2": "command example",
        "script3": "command example",
        "script4": "command example",
        "script5": "command example",
        "script6": "command example",
        "script7": "command example"
    }
    exec(obj[`script${args}`]).then(result => {
        console.log(result.stdout);
    })
}
```

Then in package.json you can have

```
"scripts": {
   "myscript": "script.sh"[or "script.js"]
}
```

then use your script as

```
npm run myscript 1
```